# Prove or disprove that this function is of class $C^{2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, derivatives

I would like to show that this function is (or not) of class $C^2$ on $\mathbb{R}$ :

$h(x)=(x-0.1)_{+}^{3} + (x-0.5)_{+}^{3}$

My guess is that this function is not of class $C^{2}$.

My first attempt was the following. Use the definition of the derivative at the point $x=0.5$ to show that the left derivative is not equal to the right derivative:

$\lim_{h\to0^{-}}\frac{h(0.5+h)-h(0.5)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^{-}}\frac{(0.4+h)^3 - 0.4^3}{h}= \lim_{h\to0^{-}}\frac{0.4^3+3\times0.4^{2}h+3\times0.4h^{2}+h^3-0.4^3}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^{-}}\frac{h(3\times0.4^{2}+3\times0.4h+h^2)}{h}=0.48$

$\lim_{h\to0^{+}}\frac{h(0.5+h)-h(0.5)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^{+}}\frac{(0.4+h)^3 +h^3 - 0.4^3}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^{+}}\frac{0.4^3+3\times0.4^{2}h+3\times0.4h^{2}+h^3+h^3-0.4^3}{h}=0.48$

I think there is a mistake since in 0.5 we should have a change too "brutal" for it to be derivable, no?

Note : the notation $(x)_{+}$ stands for $x$ if $x\geq 0$ and $0$ otherwise.

Thank you !

Comment: This function actually is $C^2$. You can see it by noticing that the summands are both $C^2$ by using that their left derivatives at $0.1$ and $0.5$ is 0, and use the chain rule to calculate their right derivatives at those points.

Comment: You're right ! The intuition goes wrong easily in calculus..  Thank you a lot !!